# How to get particular Column of DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame name it **df** I want to have like its first and second colums(series) in variable **x** and **y**.

I would have done that by name of the column like `df['A']` or `df['B']` or something like that.

But problem here is that data is itself header and it has no name.Header is like 2.17 ,3.145 like that.

So my Question is:

a) How to name column and start the data(which starts now from head) right after the name ?

b) How to get particular column's data if we don't know the name or it doesn't have the name ?

**Thank you.**

Comment: This depends on how the data is read in. Give details on how the DataFrame is created.

Comment: I read it in csv format pd.read_csv('kndkma')

Comment: May I know why downvote ? whoever did.

Comment: if your csv does not contain a header, you can use the `names` attribute to set the header manually. See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv for details.

Comment: I didn't donwvote your question, but I thought the formatting was negligent and somewhat misleading (the `or` looked like an operator). Fixed it to what I think you meant.

Comment: I also didn't downvote, but it does make answering the question much easier if you provide reusable code.

Comment: @AmiTavory Thanks for formatting and answer.I am new here and don't know much.I just wanted to know the reason so that I can improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read the 
[documentation on indexing](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html).

For what you specified in the question, you can use

```
x, y = df.iloc[:, [0]], df.iloc[:, [1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `names` kwarg when reading the DataFrame (see the [`read_csv` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

So instead of `pd.read_csv('kndkma')` use `pd.read_csv('kndkma', names=['a', 'b', ...])`.

Comment: The documentation recommends to also set `header=None`| names: "List of column names to use. If file contains no header row, then you should explicitly pass header=None"

Comment: @cel It seems redundant.

Comment: @ayhan, yes I don't think at the moment it is strictly required - yet if the documentation explicitly suggests so, I would also use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to name the columns when you read or create the DataFrame, but you can also name (or rename) the columns afterwards with something like:

```
df.columns = ['A','B', ...]
```